# Mime Type Gibberish

Tags: c#, mime-types, mime

Why is it that there are so many mime types for the same file extension? How is one supposed to determine the mime type of a file solely based on the extension, if for example there are multiple mime types associated with this extension?

```
Example:
.mp3    audio/mpeg3
.mp3    audio/x-mpeg-3
.mp3    video/mpeg
.mp3    video/x-mpeg
```

How is one supposed to know the default mime type? What does the `x-` denote? Is this a linux/unix flavor for the mime type? And why is it that none of these are standardized (yet)?

Source taken from: [Sitepoint](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full) However there are multiple other listings that produce similar spaghetti as well.

Edit:

I have a requirement that the an ASP.NET page should provide links to a few files in a source directory outside IIS. in Windows Server. I do not know what the files are, however i do know that I cannot provide full path to the file as it can be a security issue.

I am using code similar to this:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
Response.TransmitFile( '[path to file]' );
Response.End();
```

where I substitute the ContentType property for the mime type of the actual file.

Comment: An MPEG3 can be audio only or video (which might be video or audio+video).  The "x-" prefix is usually an indicator of an unratified (by a standards committee) value for the MIME type.  eXperimental and maybe have a heritage in RFC850 when headers were prefixed with X- to indicate non-specification.

Comment: Further reading https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html

Comment: To help reading comprehension; the official IANA document does not include `audio/mpeg3` among the official MIME types.  There is `audio/mpeg` which is listed as appropriate for `.mp3` (as well as `.mp1` and `.mp2`) file extensions in RFC 3003.  http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3003.txt  For MP3 video, `video/mpeg` would seem suitable; it goes all the way back to RFC 2046.  http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt

Comment: And no, one is not supposed to determine the file type based solely on the extension.  Various multimedia container formats such as `.mp3` can hold various types of streams, and you have to inspect the file to find out what sort of streams they are.  If your web server cannot do this, or you don't want to, you'll have to preprocess the files and rename them unambiguously so that the web server can map from the file extension to the correct MIME type, but of course, this has some undesirable consequences.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Framework 4.5 you can get the mimemapping using:

```
var mapping = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("something.jpg");
```

If you're using Framework 4 you can access a non-public method to do the same like so:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a");
var assemblyType = assembly.GetType("System.Web.MimeMapping");

var getMimeMappingMethod = assemblyType.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic) ??
                           assemblyType.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

var mapping = (string)getMimeMappingMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { fileName });
```